# Set heights of a row of components dynamically based on the tallest one

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have three components called blog cards that are rendered with an image and text. Depending on how long the text is the cards are of different heights. I want to render them, then get the tallest one, and sort of re-render them, so they are all the same height.

Here is the Page

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { SocialIconRow } from '@/components/social-icons'
import BlogPostCard from '@/components/BlogCard'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { FixedSizeList } from 'react-window'

function BlogPostCardsList({ cards }) {
  const tallestCardHeight = useMemo(() => {
    return Math.max(...cards.map(card => card.height))
  }, [cards])

  return (
    <FixedSizeList
      itemCount={cards.length}
      itemSize={tallestCardHeight}
      width={'100%'}
      height={'100%'}
    >
      {({ index, style }) => <BlogPostCard style={style} {...cards[index]} />}
    </FixedSizeList>
  )
}


export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const [cardHeight, setCardHeight] = useState(null);
const [maxHeight, setMaxHeight] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const calculateHeight = () => {
        const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.blog-post-card');
        let heights = [];
        cards.forEach(card => {
            heights.push(card.clientHeight);
        });
        setMaxHeight(Math.max(...heights));
    }
    calculateHeight();
    setCardHeight(maxHeight);
}, []);


  return (
    <>
      <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-col">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex">
      <div className="w-1/2 pr-4">
        <div className="text-4xl font-bold">Mike Borman</div>
        <div className="text-lg mt-2">Writer, Content Creator and Developer on Cardano</div>
      </div>
  <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col justify-center">
    <div className="max-h-48 max-w-48 mx-auto my-auto">
    <Image
      src="/images/myfaceppgray.png"
      alt="Picture of the author"
      className="max-h-48 max-w-48"
      width="150"
      height="150"
      unoptimized={true}
    />
    </div>
    <div className="mt-4">
      <SocialIconRow className="social-icon-row" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div className="mt-8">
    <div className="text-3xl font-bold">Featured Blogs</div>
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 h-full mt-4 align-items-stretch">
      <div  style={{height: cardHeight}}>
        <BlogPostCard
          title="The Hydra Protocol Family — Scaling and Network Optimization for the Cardano Blockchain"
          slug="the-hydra-protocol-family-scaling-and-network-optimization-for-the-cardano-blockchain"
          imageslug="/images/hydra.png"
          className="blog-post-card"
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{height: cardHeight}}>
        <BlogPostCard
          title="Ouroboros, A deep dive for non PhDs"
          slug="ouroboros-a-deep-dive-for-non-phd"
          imageslug="/images/ourobouros.png"
          className="blog-post-card"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="h-full row-auto" style={{height: cardHeight}}>
        <BlogPostCard
          title="Ouroboros, A deep dive for non PhDs"
          slug="ouroboros-a-deep-dive-for-non-phd"
          imageslug="/images/ourobouros.png"
          className="blog-post-card"
        />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
      
      
    </>
  )
}
```

Here is the Card component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'

function BlogPostCard(props) {
  const { title, slug, imageslug } = props

  return (
    <Link href={`/blog/${slug}`}>
    <a className="block flex flex-col justify-between rounded-md border-2 border-teal-400 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-lg">
    <img className="rounded-t-md h-48 w-full object-cover" src={imageslug} alt="blog post cover" />
    <span className="text-white text-2xl p-4">{title}</span>
    </a>
  </Link>
  )
}

export default BlogPostCard
```

I tried dynamically rendering them then setting them, btw I have no idea really what Im doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have all but one class already to do this entirely in CSS.  Just add `h-full` to your `a` tag inside the `BlogPostCard` component's `Link`.  Then you can get rid of all of the JS.  Optionally, you could also remove the `justify-between` or change it to `justify-stretch` so that the titles of the blog posts are directly beneath of the post cover images.

In the demo below, you can see the result by clicking run code snippet.  Also, if you're upgrading to NextJS 13, it's worth noting that you no longer need (and in fact can't have) an `a` tag as a child of `Link`.  I'd suggest using `article` as I've done below, which will be more semantically correct anyway.

```js
function BlogPage({posts}) {
  return (
    <main className="container mx-auto my-8">
      <div className="flex gap-4">
        <div className="w-1/2">
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Mike Borman</h1>
          <h2 className="text-lg mt-2">
            Writer, Content Creator and Developer on Cardano
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <span className="w-[150px] h-[150px] bg-neutral-300 rounded-full grid place-content-center">author img here</span>
          <span>social row here</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section className="mt-8">
        <header>
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold">Featured Blogs</h2>
        </header>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 h-full mt-4 align-items-stretch">
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <BlogPostCard key={post.id} {...post} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  ) 
}

function BlogPostCard({ slug, imageslug, title,}) {
  return (
    <Link href={`/blog/${slug}`}>
      <article className="flex flex-col justify-stretch h-full rounded-md border-2 border-teal-400 bg-neutral-600 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-lg">
        <img
          className="rounded-t-md h-48 w-full object-cover"
          src={imageslug}
          alt="blog post cover"
        />
        <span className="text-white text-2xl p-4">{title}</span>
      </article>
    </Link>
  )
}

/* Stubbing out next/link here since I can't run NextJS in code snippets */
function Link({ href, children, className }) {
  return (
    <a href={href} className={className}>
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<BlogPage posts={[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'The Hydra Protocol Family — Scaling and Network Optimization for the Cardano Blockchain',
    slug: 'the-hydra-protocol-family-scaling-and-network-optimization-for-the-cardano-blockchain',
    imageslug: 'https://d3lkc3n5th01x7.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/15233606/700-X-394.png',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Ouroboros, A deep dive for non PhDs',
    slug: 'ouroboros-a-deep-dive-for-non-phd',
    imageslug: 'https://www.almaviva.it/dam/jcr:6212e8ef-1ed6-40e2-a75f-b6fa7c814662/Blockchain_1280x720.jpg',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'How Blockchain Is Used',
    slug: 'how-blockchain-is-used',
    imageslug: 'https://imageio.forbes.com/specials-images/imageserve/5f2a32ee3b52675a453e2881/Fascinating-Examples-Of-How-Blockchain-Is-Used-In-Insurance--Banking-And-Travel/960x0.jpg?format=jpg&width=960',
  },
]} />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thats excellent thanks, spent all day trying to figure that out haha